# Sending multiple arguments to function in python including 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am trying to index 2D array "matrix" in these two functions. The indexing works well in the "findMin" function, but for the "plotContours" function, I keep getting the following error: **"TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable"**

What is the best way to pass a 2D array to a function that also contains integers in the arguments? The 2D array "matrix" is the same variable that I send to both functions.

Here are the two functions:

```
def findMin(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):... 
         [array index processing]
    return xyz

def plotContours(matrix, max, min, range):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):...
        [array index processing]
    return xyz
```

Comment: `max`, `min` and `range` are predefined functions in Python, you cannot use them as variables.

Comment: @MrGeek, yes you can, but that's exactly why there's a problem here.

Comment: @MrGeek: you can, but then you *override* the builtin.

Comment: @alexis and WillemVanOnsem thanks for the clarification, but it's still not a good practice, and in this case, range is the problem.

Comment: Yes, "not good practice" hits the nail on the head. When the builtin is not used it's not obvious why it shouldn't be shadowed (the OP might not even know that `min` and `max` are builtins), but this question is a textbook example of why.

Comment: Thanks all, I didn't realize range could not be used as a variable!

Comment: Well it's a bad idea, precisely because of problems like this. But it _can_ be used as a variable, as long as you don't *also* use it with its original meaning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you call `plotContours()`, but since one of its arguments is called range, you don't have access to the Python `range()` function inside `plotContours()`: Instead, `range` is whatever you passed as the fourth argument. You seem to pass a `numpy.float64` object, which you then attempt to "call" as if it was a function.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize the range call was problematic!